# separate a .txt file into two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, txt

I have a .txt file, without header. I am going to separate into two column with header X and Y that is ordered like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTEM8.png)

I have read text file into pandas:

How can I have data frame with two column and header X and Y?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGbxk.png)

Comment: (1) Please post your code (and your data, in this case) as _text_, not images. (2) Your code doesn't show anything Pandas-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(
  "reference.txt",
  delim_whitespace=True,  # any whitespace separates data
  names=["x", "y"],  # column names
  index_col=False,  # no index
)
```

ought to do the trick.

Comment: my values in .txt file are scientific e notation. when I run this code, the value have shown in this format, is it going wrong?

Comment: You can use `dtype={'x': np.float64, 'y': np.float64}` if you need to cast the columns.

Comment: sorry, I ask my question wrong. I want to value stay scientific e notation. but when I see them they are folat

Comment: Then use the `str` dtype.

Comment: I wrote dtypre = str , but when I wanted to get by using this df['x'] or iloc[: , 0], it returns values in float